# Script para desligar o computador ao fechar um determinado programa

Tags: linux, shell-script

Como faço para criar um script para que quando a janela do rdesktop for fechada o computador seja desligado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

André Cabral

Seria fechar um programa ou uma janela?

Considerando um programa qualquer:

Crie um arquivo com o nome que você quiser, os exemplos abaixo referem-se ao ubuntu:

```
touch desliga_automatico
```

Coloque a permissão para executar:

```
sudo chmod +x desliga_automatico
```

Coloque o código abaixo:

```
#!/bin/sh
PROGRAMA='rdesktop' #nome do programa que deseja monitorar

while [ TRUE ] 
do
    if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $PROGRAMA > /dev/null
    then
        #echo "$PROGRAMA está rodando"
    else
        #echo "$PROGRAMA não está rodando"
        sudo reboot 
    fi
    # colocamos o sleep para o processador ter tempo para realizar outras tarefas
    # você pode colocar o tempo que achar melhor (em segundos)
    sleep 120
done
```

---

No caso de ser uma janela e não um programa:

```
#!/bin/sh
PROGRAMA='rdesktop'

while [ TRUE ]
do

    if xlsclients | grep -v grep | grep $PROGRAMA > /dev/null
    then
        #echo "$PROGRAMA está rodando"
    else
        echo "$PROGRAMA não está rodando"
        sudo reboot
    fi
    # colocamos o sleep para o processador ter tempo para realizar outras tarefas
    # você pode colocar o tempo que achar melhor (em segundos)
    sleep 120
done
```

---

Se isso atender sua necessidade você pode coloca-lo em:

```
sudo mv desliga_automatico /etc/init.d/
```

para ele iniciar toda a vez que o computador for iniciado

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Edita a resposta. Ela está boa, mas colocar em `/etc/init.d/` não basta pra rodar a aplicação no *boot*. Além de dar permissão, tem que atualizar os *runlevels* E pra rodar no *boot* tb tem que alterar o cabeçalho da aplicação citando os *runlevels*, etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/sh
PROGRAMA='rdesktop'

while [ TRUE ]
do

    if xlsclients | grep -v grep | grep $PROGRAMA > /dev/null
    then
        echo "$PROGRAMA está rodando"
    else
        echo "$PROGRAMA não está rodando"
        sudo reboot
    fi
    # colocamos o sleep para o processador ter tempo para realizar outras tarefas
    # você pode colocar o tempo que achar melhor (em segundos)
    sleep 120
done
```

PS: Tinha uma linha comentada antes do Else por isso o codigo da erro, agora ta certo!